# this inside iife points to window?

Tags: javascript, this

Learning about **this** in JavaScript. I am confused about the scope of this inside iife. Why this points to window object inside iife? This should points to myObj because it is inside myObj.

```js
window.foo = "bar1";
var myObj = {
   foo: "bar2",
   func: function() {
       var self = this;
       console.log(this.foo + ", " + self.foo);
       (function xx() {
           console.log(this.foo + ", " + self.foo)
       }());
   }
}
myObj.func();
```

Output -

> bar2, bar2 
>   bar1, bar2

I am concerned about bar1 in second line.

Comment: `this` will be `window`, correct. You're not in strict mode and you're not executing the IIFE with any context, so `this` defaults to `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `xx` is called as IIFE, which is a simple function call. As per the spec, in simple function call, the global object (window in browser) is assigned to `this`.

```js
window.foo = "bar1";
var myObj = {
   foo: "bar2",
   func: function() {
       var self = this;
       console.log(this.foo + ", " + self.foo);
       (function xx() {
           console.log(`this === window :`, this === window);
           console.log(this.foo + ", " + self.foo)
       }());
   }
}
myObj.func();
```

Reference:

> Since the following code is not in strict mode, and because the value of `this` is not set by the call, this will default to the global object, which is window in a browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this